# How to size tab in html

Tags: html, css, tabs

I'm trying to size a tab tag in HTML. I need to adjust the size of the tab to the size of the buttons.

[image]

```css
#economic_data_layout_tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333333;
    tab-size: 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" id="economic_data_layout_tab">
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showPreviousYearLayout()">Previous year</button>
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showActualYearLayout()">Actual year</button>
</div>
```

Any suggestion?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Better if you can share a code snippet with both html and CSS. Also please mention which one is your button and tab

Comment: Added the html code. @Kiran Dash

Comment: Modified your code to create a snippet. Can you explain what is your expectation

Comment: It's because the div element by default is a block element. The block element takes all the possible width of a screen. Try to play with display property for the div element.

Comment: @arevilla009 I guess you want the div to have width based on it's content. Just use CSS `display: inline-block` See a working solution in the answer.

Comment: The property display: inline-block; worked, thanks! @KiranDash

Comment: @arevilla009 Great. If it is resolved. Kindly close the post by marking one of the post as your answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default `div` tag has `display: block` style which means it will take full width of parent. Since you want it to take width as per it's content, just overwrite the CSS to `display: inline-block`.

Alternatively, you can also use `float:left` if you want.

**Solution 1: With display inline**

```css
#economic_data_layout_tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333333;
    tab-size: 4;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" id="economic_data_layout_tab">
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showPreviousYearLayout()">Previous year</button>
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showActualYearLayout()">Actual year</button>
</div>
```

**Solution 2: With float**

```css
#economic_data_layout_tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333333;
    tab-size: 4;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab" id="economic_data_layout_tab">
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showPreviousYearLayout()">Previous year</button>
     <button class="tablinks" onclick="showActualYearLayout()">Actual year</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Great. Glad to help. Since it worked for you. Kindly close the post by marking one of the post as your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Done I think. @Kiran Dash